# What all is migrated when doing an export/import in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: migration

I have used SharePoint's export/import tool in SharePoint 2007... Wasn't too thrilled with it. I am now having to do the same thing in SharePoint 2010. First off, just as a refresher, what all is migrated when using the export/import utility? And, is the export/import the same in SP 2010 as it was in SP 2007? If any issues have been seen with the SP2010 export/import utility, I would like to hear that as well. Thanks in advance.

Comment: To which import/export tool do you refer?  The command line tool or the Content Deployment Wizard?

Comment: I'm talking about the Central Admin wizard tool to export and import a site collection

Answer (score 1):

if you refer to the Microsoft.Sharepoint.Deployment API and the methodes

SPImport/SPExport

the documentation does not show any difference between SP2007 and SP2010

What is migrated when using export/import?

"The following content does not get captured by the Content Migration API - alerts, audit trail, change log history, recycle-bin items, workflow tasks/state."

Note that the "Content Deployment Wizard" uses the Microsoft.Sharepoint.Deployment (SPImport/SPExport)